# Django multiple pictures one product

Tags: django, database, model, admin

I have the following problem: I'm programming a webshop and every product has multiple pictures. So this is a one-to-many relation, where the foreign key is in the picture model. However, if i register the models "product" and "picture" to the admin site the user obviously needs to add a product then navigate to the pictures and add a picture and referencing a product within the picture creation process. Instead of this i want the user to be able to create a product and then add multiple pictures in the dropdown menu inside the same subpage inside admin-pannel. How can i accomplish this behaviour? It should look exact like it would with a many-to-many relation. But i don't want to use ManyToManyField sience i already tried it and then it lead to logical issues.

models.py:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/static/shop/images/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.picture.url

class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Picture)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/static/shop/images/')  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.picture.url

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class PictureInline(modeladmin.StackedInline):
    model = Picture
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PictureInline]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

#NOTE: dont register you Picture model because you have put inline in product so from here you can directly put you pictures in the product.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/static/shop/images/')
    def __str__(self):
         return self.picture.url

class Product(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     product = models.ManyToManyField(Picture, blank=True,related_name="product_img")

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Try using this instead.